# Unhandled exception "System.IndexOutOfRangeException"

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

```
Module Module1

'input vars declarations
Private DescriptionString As String
Private StockNumberString As String
Private WholesalePriceDecimal As Decimal
Private QuantityOHDecimal As Decimal

'CONSTANT VAR
Private Const PROFIT_PERCENT_DECIMAL As Decimal = 0.25

'calculated vars declarations
Private InvValueDecimal As Decimal 'this is WholesalePrice * QOH
Private PotentialProfit As Decimal 'this is InvValue * PROFIT_PERCENT
Private PotentialIncome As Decimal 'this is InvValue + PotentialProfit

'declares the record variable and associates file name
Private CurrentRecord()
Private FurnitureInventoryFile As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("FURNFILE.TXT")

'Main module is Level 1
Sub Main()

    'L1 calls L2

    Call Housekeeping()

    Do While Not FurnitureInventoryFile.EndOfData
        Call ProcessRecords()
    Loop

    Call EndOfJob()

End Sub

'L2 Housekeeping() calls L3 SetFileDelimiter() and L3 WriteHeadings()
Private Sub Housekeeping()

    Call SetFileDelimiter()
    Call WriteHeadings()

End Sub

'L2 ProcessRecords() calls L3 ReadFile(), L3 DetailCalculations() and L3 WriteDetailLine()
Private Sub ProcessRecords()

    Call ReadFile()
    Call DetailCalculations()
    Call WriteDetailLine()

End Sub

'L2 EndOfJob() calls L3 SummaryOutput() and L3 CloseFile()
Private Sub EndOfJob()

    Call SummaryOutput()
    Call CloseFile()

End Sub

'L3, Called by Housekeeping(), Assigns filetype as delimited and assigns the delimiter as a comma
Private Sub SetFileDelimiter()

    FurnitureInventoryFile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    FurnitureInventoryFile.SetDelimiters(",")

End Sub

'L3, Called by Housekeeping(), Writes the report heading and column heading lines
Private Sub WriteHeadings()

    'Report Headings
    Console.WriteLine(Space(17) & "Inventory Report for Quality Furniture Store")
    Console.WriteLine(Space(28) & "Christian VanderHorst")

    '2 Blank lines
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    'Column Headings
    Console.WriteLine(Space(22) & "Stock" & Space(8) & "Wholesale" & Space(2) & "Inventory" & Space(2) & "Potential" & Space(3) & "Potential")
    Console.WriteLine(Space(1) & "Description" & Space(10) & "Number" & Space(2) & "QOH" & Space(6) & "Price" & Space(6) & "Value" & Space(5) & "Profit" & Space(6) & "Income")

End Sub

'L3, Called by ProcessRecords(), Reads the file and parses the current record into its vars
Private Sub ReadFile()

    CurrentRecord = FurnitureInventoryFile.ReadFields() 'reads the record

    StockNumberString = CurrentRecord(0)
    DescriptionString = CurrentRecord(1)
    WholesalePriceDecimal = CurrentRecord(2)
    QuantityOHDecimal = CurrentRecord(3)

End Sub

'L3, Calculates InvValueDecimal, PotentialProfitDecimal and PotentialIncomeDecimal
Private Sub DetailCalculations()

    InvValueDecimal = WholesalePriceDecimal * QuantityOHDecimal
    PotentialProfit = InvValueDecimal * PROFIT_PERCENT_DECIMAL
    PotentialIncome = InvValueDecimal + PotentialProfit

End Sub

'L3, Writes the detail lines
Private Sub WriteDetailLine()

    Console.WriteLine(Space(1) & DescriptionString.PadRight(19) &
                      Space(2) & StockNumberString &
                      Space(4) & QuantityOHDecimal.ToString("N0").PadLeft(2) &
                      Space(3) & WholesalePriceDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(8) &
                      Space(2) & InvValueDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(9) &
                      Space(5) & PotentialProfit.ToString("N").PadLeft(5) &
                      Space(2) & PotentialIncome.ToString("C").PadLeft(10))

End Sub

'L3, Writes the summary line and pauses program to wait for enter keystroke
Private Sub SummaryOutput()

    'Blank space to move the summary line down
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    'the summary line
    Console.WriteLine(Space(24) & "End of Furniture Profit Report")

    'prompt to tell the user how to close the report
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close the report")
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

'L3, Closes the input file
Private Sub CloseFile()

    FurnitureInventoryFile.Close()

End Sub
```

End Module

This is the complete code ive created. It all works fine, however, after outputting 3 detail lines, it comes up with

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in My_Name.InvReportFurniture.exe
>
> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

And specifies the statement

> QuantityOHDecimal = CurrentRecord(3)

as the source

I cant seem to figure out what the cause of it is. If i put a pause between every detail line write, it happens the same way throwing that exception after the 3rd detail line.

Here is the data file.

> ET010,3 Drawer End table, 169.00, 10
> ET020,4 Drawer End table, 299.95, 05
> ET030,8 Drawer End table, 148.99, 12
> ST010,Stacking Table      325.50, 20
> BC020,4 Shelf Book Case,  130.99, 24
> BC030,5 Shelf Book Case,  199.95, 08
> BC040,6 Shelf Book Case,  270.99, 15
> LC010,Lounge Chair,       198.89, 20
> VC010,Wingback Chair,     320.55, 05
> LC011,Pleather Recliner, 1050.00, 02
> FC010,Fabric Recliner,    755.00, 04
> VC015,Leather Recliner,   500.01, 10
> BS010,Book Stand,         235.80, 05
> LS010,Lamp Stand,         135.23, 15
> PS010,Phone Stand,         99.95, 19
> TS010,TV Stand,           270.90, 08
> SS010,Stereo Stand,       675.00, 15
> TS015,Tiffany Stand,     1115.35, 02

Comment: You should set `Option Strict On`.  Also, Classes and collections would simplify the code greatly

Answer (score 3):

It's because the row with ST010 is missing a comma field delimiter.  You only have three fields in this row, so field index 3 (fourth field) does not exist.

Comment: Gah! You beat me too it!